# Warning when trying to install angular2 dropdown multiselect library

Tags: angular

I am trying to install angular 2 drop down multi select library by running the following command

npm install angular-2-dropdown-multiselect --save-dev

But I get this warning message "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect@1.3.2 requires a peer of tslib@^1.6.1 but none was installed."

I have no clue what this means. Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about tslib here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/tslib

In the `README.md`, you will find  `npm install tslib@1.6.1`. See if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I didn't try installing tslib but I tried upgrading my angular-cli version and that helped. Thanks!